# pip install from github on heroku cedar stack

Tags: python, heroku, virtualenv, pip

I have several python modules that I need to install from HEAD revisions on github into an application's virtualenv on heroku. I have tried several incarnations of the following command:

heroku run  bin/python bin/pip install -E /app --upgrade git+git://github.com/whoever/whatever.git

The command succeeds but the module isn't there afterward. I've tried this with and without the -E and also with . instead of /app for the -E. Also, with and without the --upgrade.

How do I install a python module from github to heroku with pip in virtualenv on the cedar stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

heroku run spins up a new dyno and runs the command you specify in that dyno only. Dynos are ephemeral which is why it must be a git push and specified within your requirements.txt

You can include a git repo without the -e based on the format specified on the pip installer page: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#version-control-systems